# CS50 Week 2 Substitution: Converting a string to uppercase

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to convert a string to all uppercase using below:

```
string key = argv[1];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if islower(key[i])
        {
            toupper(key[i]);
        }
    }
```

I'm receiving:

```
substitution.c:59:13: error: ignoring return value of function declared with pure attribute [-Werror,-Wunused-value]
            toupper(key[i]);
```

Could anyone help me understand what this means?

The other part of the code is listed below if that's relevant.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // strlen = 26
    int len = strlen(argv[1]);
    if (len != 26)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // input must be single string
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // check each char as letter
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(argv[1][i]))
        {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
        }
    }
    // check for duplicates
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++)
        {
            if (toupper((argv[1][i])) == toupper((argv[1][j])))
            {
                printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Trying to convert a string to all uppercase but ran into an error that I can't understand. Thanks!

Comment: It means you're calling toupper() then throwing away the result. You need to assign the result to something.

Comment: Your function call has the same effect as if you just write `5;` or `;`. This function does not modify the parameter. It returns a converted value which you need to store.

Comment: `if islower(key[i])` is syntactically incorrect. Please make sure to post a complete [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking questions. Copy and paste your example into the question - do not transcribe by hand.

Answer (score 1):

**From the man page:**

*DESCRIPTION:*

> These functions convert lowercase letters to uppercase, and vice versa.

> If c is a lowercase letter, toupper() returns its uppercase equivalent, if an uppercase representation exists in the current locale.  Otherwise, it returns c. The toupper_l() function
> performs the same task, but uses the locale referred to by the locale handle locale.

> If c is an uppercase letter, tolower() returns its lowercase equivalent, if a lowercase representation exists in the current locale.  Otherwise, it returns c. The tolower_l() function performs the same task, but uses the locale referred to by the locale handle locale.

**OP's Problem:**

```
toupper(key[i])
```

does not change the supplied argument. It returns the uppercase equivalent of the character, if available. You need to make use of it.

Change this:

```
toupper(key[i);
```

to:

```
key[i] = toupper(key[i]);
```

You're also missing a pair of parentheses around the if statement.

Comment: Also good to note that the argument to any of the `ctype.h` functions (macros) must be representable as `unsigned char`. A pedantic use would be `key[i] = toupper((unsigned char)key[i]);`. See [C18 Standard - 7.4 Character handling <ctype.h>(p1)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf#section.7.4) Good job on the nicely formatted answer.